# Java: enter list from keyboard missing data

Tags: java

write a Java program to create a list, to enter the values from keyboard and then print the value of this list, but when I enter 1 3 5 7 9, the output is only 1,3,5,     where is 7 and 9,  could you please help me for that

```
public class MergeTwoSortedList {
    public static class ListNode{
        int value;
        ListNode next;
        public ListNode(int n){
            this.value = n;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // input two integer lists
        System.out.println("please input list1");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ListNode head = null;
        if(in.hasNextInt()){
            head = new ListNode(in.nextInt());
        }
        ListNode temp = head;
        while(in.hasNextInt()){
            temp.next = new ListNode(in.nextInt());
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        in.close();
        ListNode list1 = head;

        while(list1.next != null){

            System.out.print(list1.value + ",");
            list1 = list1.next;
        }

        System.out.println();



    }


}
```

when running it ,it print:

```
please input list1
1 3 5 7 9;
1,3,5,
```

where is 7 and 9

Comment: why are you entering `;` after input ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: it is not homework, I promise, it is a problem I met when I learning Java

Comment: to mohsen_fatemi, where is the ";" do you mentioned

Comment: Fair enough.  Most of the post still applies.

Answer (score 1):

In your example input `1 3 5 7 9;` the `9;` is treated as `String` so it won't be added to your list since you're calling `in.hasNextInt()`.
To fix this problem you can write a whitespace after you finish entering your numbers, so in your example the correct input would look like this:

`1 3 5 7 9 ;`

Another problem with your code is you condition in the
`while(list1.next != null)` loop.
If you analyze your code step by step, you'll see that when `list1` becomes the last node, you check if it has the next node and end the loop without printing the last value.
The solution is really simple, just change your while condition to this:

```
while(list1 != null){
    System.out.print(list1.value + ",");
    list1 = list1.next;
}
```

This way you'll end the loop the after printing the last element.

Comment: @bin No problem. Please accept this answer if it helped.